# After LinearRegression Model, How to Pair the Coefficients with the corresponding Features?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, data-analysis

I built my first LinearRegression model (ElasticNet),  predicting house SalePrice.

I would like to find out the features that have strong correlations (both negative and positive correlations) with the SalePrice

In the screenshot, I listed out all the coefficient and feature names. **What code can I use to pair these two values so I can see each feature's coefficient value?**

I am very new to coding and data analytics. Thank you in advance!

**My model:**

```
grid_model = GridSearchCV(estimator = base_elastic_model,
                     param_grid = param_grid,
                     scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error',
                     cv=5,
                     verbose=1)
grid_model.fit(scaled_X_train,y_train)
```

**I got the list of coefficient:**

```
grid_model.fit(scaled_X_train,y_train)
```

**I got the list of features whose coefficent with the SalePrice is not 0**

```
df.columns[coef[coef == 0].index]
```

How can i print a dataframe with Coefficient and Feature Name listed matching each other?

Comment: Will you please `print(grid_model.fit(scaled_X_train,y_train))`, and `print(df.columns[coef[coef == 0].index])`, and add that to the question?

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame` to create that dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.DataFrame(X_train.columns, grid_model.best_estimator_.coef_)
```

It will give output like this:

```
-0.003801   feature0
-0.033107   feature1
0.053203    feature2
-0.645900   feature3
-7.474264   feature4
-0.571417   feature5
0.007333    feature6
0.184133    feature7
0.091905    feature8
0.002021    feature9
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I then try to sort the absolute value to rank the largest coefficient (both negative and positive correlated) by the code below but got error message: coef_df.sort_values('grid_model.best_estimator_.coef_').Could you please guide?

Comment: i upvoted your solution but my reputation is below 15 so it doesnt show. It says my upvote has been recorded though

Comment: If this solved your question, please accept it by clicking on the tick mark button.

Comment: `coef_df = coef_df.reset_index()                                                 
coef_df.sort_values('index', ascending=False)` you can use this code to sort values